# Is there an API for programmatically creating saved searches in Google Logs Explorer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

Using Google [Logs Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-viewer-interface) it's possible to save searches and even share them with others.  I'd like to manage a set of shared searches programatically so that my team and I can store search definitions in Git and have automation apply any updates to these definitions.

Does anyone know if there is an official API for managing and sharing these saved searches?  I don't mind if this is a REST API, a Golang API, or through gcloud commands.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is an API that is specific to Logs explorer. But rather for [cloud logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest) that writes log entries and manages the Cloud Logging configuration. Using the interface to [create the saved searches](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/building-queries#saved-queries) and share the queries may help and  you are able to [download the logs in CSV or JSON format](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-viewer-interface#download_logs).

Also you can use [regular expressions in the Query builder and with gcloud command-line tool](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-viewer-interface#download_logs).

Please review these [features in the Logs Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-viewer-preview#existing_and_upcoming_features).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I had reviewed the gcloud docs and golang APIs before posting my question and didn't find any mention of an API to programatically configure Logs Explorer.  I was hoping that maybe the API existed but I hadn't been able to find documentation for it.  Unfortunately, as we use multiple GKE projects where I work we would need an API as it's not feasible or desirable to manually save and share the search in each GKE project (and I do not believe it's possible to share a search across GKE projects).